# multiple systemd-fcsk message on Debian 8.1 boot

Tags: debian, boot

Suddenly, when booting my computer, I see several messages like this:

`[     16.123575] systemd-fsck[337]: , 408::f6/00, 306::c6/00, 408::f6/00, ...`

and in the end:

`Not automatically fixing this`

What does it mean? Do I need to completely format my entire HDD?

Here's the image of my screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `fsck` have detected issues on one of your partitions, and it's unable to fix them automatically. If you keep using a filesystem which has errors, its state may worsen up to the point you will not be able to mount it properly anymore.

You should check your partitions with `fsck` as soon as possible. Bear in mind that `fsck` cannot fix partitions which are mounted in "read/write" mode. You can simply unmount a partition before running `fsck`:

```
sudo umount /dev/partition
sudo fsck /dev/partition
```

Note that you cannot unmount the partition which is mounted as root. To check the root partition, refer to [these answers](https://superuser.com/questions/401217/how-to-check-root-partition-with-fsck).